# How does a believer behold as in the mirror the glory of the Lord in 2 Corinthians 3:18?

Tags: 2-corinthians, metaphor

> But **we all, with unveiled face, beholding as in a mirror the glory of the Lord**, are being transformed into the same image from glory to glory, just as from the Lord, the Spirit. 2 Corinthians 3:18 (NASB)

How does a believer ‘behold as in the mirror the glory of the Lord’ as in 2 Corinthians 3:18?

Answer (score 8):

The verse in question comes in a passage comparing and contrasting Law versus Spirit and the glory from such. So the immediate context of 2 Cor 3:18 is vv.4-18, here in the NKJV:

> 4 And we have such trust through Christ toward God. 5 Not that we are sufficient of ourselves to think of anything as being from ourselves, but our sufficiency is from God, 6 who also made us sufficient as ministers of the new covenant, not of the letter but of the Spirit; for the letter kills, but the Spirit gives life. 7 But if the ministry of death, written and engraved on stones, was glorious, so that the children of Israel could not look steadily at the face of Moses because of the glory of his countenance, which glory was passing away, 8 how will the ministry of the Spirit not be more glorious? 9 For if the ministry of condemnation had glory, the ministry of righteousness exceeds much more in glory. 10 For even what was made glorious had no glory in this respect, because of the glory that excels. 11 For if what is passing away was glorious, what remains is much more glorious. 12 Therefore, since we have such hope, we use great boldness of speech—13 unlike Moses, who put a veil over his face so that the children of Israel could not look steadily at the end of what was passing away. 14 But their minds were blinded. For until this day the same veil remains unlifted in the reading of the Old Testament, because the veil is taken away in Christ. 15 But even to this day, when Moses is read, a veil lies on their heart. 16 Nevertheless when one turns to the Lord, the veil is taken away. 17 Now the Lord is the Spirit; and where the Spirit of the Lord is, there is liberty. 18 But we all, with unveiled face, beholding as in a mirror the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into the same image from glory to glory, just as by the Spirit of the Lord.

So follow the glory. We'll pick it up in v.7—

Verse 7 states the giving of the Law, which brought death (see also v.6), was a glorious thing (v.7a), but the glory from Moses's face (v.7b) was not from receiving that Law, but from being in God's presence during that giving, from having "talked with Him [YHWH]" (Ex 34:29, 34), and so reflecting God's glory out to the people of Israel.

Verses 8-10 ask a rhetorical question and answer, if the "ministry of death" brought such glory, how can the "ministry of the Spirit" (which is life, v.6) not be more glorious, since it is comparing the glory of condemnation to that of righteousness. So much so, that it makes the first glory pale in comparison (v.10).

Verse 11 indicates that the former glory (Law/Death) is fading, but the latter, greater glory (Spirit/Life) will remain.

Verses 12-13 refers to this ministry of the Spirit as a "hope" that is worth boldly proclaiming (v.12), and not something to be hid as Moses was having to do when Israel could not look upon His reflection of God upon His face for the lesser glory that will pass (v.13).

Verses 14-17 reveals that the reason Israel could not look upon the glory reflecting off Moses was that their minds were blind to wanting to see truth (v.14a), and that same blindness to truth affects their reading of the OT still (v.14b and 15), until faith in Christ comes (v.14c) and takes it away (v.16), because then one has the Spirit (the greater glory) within them and this brings a freedom from the blindness to truth (v.17).

Verse 18 then states "we all" (i.e. believers, those that are "in Christ," v.4) are "made ... sufficient as minister of the new covenant" (v.6) by the Spirit in us and working through us. So we have an "unveiled face" (v.18a), we do not suppress the truth of Christ and the life we have through Him (cf. Rom 1:18), but reflect it back upon ourselves, "beholding as in a mirror the glory of the Lord" (v.18b), and in looking upon that truth, "are being transformed into the same image from glory to glory" (v.18c), "by the Spirit of the Lord" (v.18d).

#### Conclusion

So having the truth, proclaiming the truth, and **reflecting on that truth in our own lives, letting that truth change them to be more like God** (this is the "answer" to the OP's question of "how" this is done; "beholding" is the middle participle, so it emphasizes the idea of "looking at oneself"; if it meant just "reflecting" to others, it would have been in active voice<sup>`1`</sup>) works to *increase* our reflection of God's glory. We grow from one stage of glory to another ("being transformed" is a present passive indicative, so it emphasizes a process), until we come to our bodily resurrection (Phil 3:21; 1 Cor 15:40) and the full attainment of reflecting God's glory (Rom 5:2, 8:18, 8:30, 9:23; made like Christ, 1 Jn 3:2, the one human who never failed at being the express image of God, Heb 1:3) as God originally designed humanity to do in being made like Him (Gen 1:26).

---

**NOTES**

<sup>`1`</sup> William Arndt, Frederick W. Danker, Walter Bauer, and F. Wilbur Gingrich, *A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature* (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2000), s.v. κατοπτρίζω.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer :-) Do you think the NIV translation of [2 Corinthians 3:18](https://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/3-18.htm)  is a bit more clearer? *"And we all, who with unveiled faces **contemplate the Lord's glory**, are being transformed into his image with ever-increasing glory, which comes from the Lord, who is the Spirit."*

Comment: Personally, no. First, I always favor a more literal translation, keeping *interpretation* to a minimum in the *translation* process. The word in the text has the idea of reflecting/looking in a mirror, and so I think it is best to keep that. Second, related to the first, is the NIV translation loses the "self-contemplation" aspect. That is, it is the Lord's glory as seen/reflected in/through *me* and *my unveiled face*, which the word picture of beholding in a mirror conveys that in a way that merely "contemplate the Lord's glory" does not.

Comment: @SijuGeorge Your welcome. I see you opted to still award the bounty to one of the original answers. I'm glad my answer was still helpful to you.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, it was a mistake :-( I was supposed to award it to you. Some distraction came in between and the bounty button that was visible on the page was of the next answer. I apologize. It can't be undone I guess!

Comment: @SijuGeorge No problem. I'm not exactly in need of reputation. I tend to key in on Featured questions because I know someone really wants an answer since they are offering reputation, and so that makes it worth my time to answer.

Comment: Thanks a million. I am struggling in the area of sanctification and your answer was a big factor for solving one of my puzzles regarding it. In a way I am happy you did not get the 100 points because you deserve much more than that. Our just Lord will reward you eternally.

Comment: Found out that bounty can be awarded even later. So thought of giving you 200 since I did a mistake last time :-)

Answer (score 2):

The Christian Scriptures are the mirror, by which the Spirit of God reflects to the believer ones new identity in Jesus Christ. That is, upon conversion the Christian receives a new and glorious identity as a result of union with the death and resurrection of Jesus Christ ([Rom 6:5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans%206%3A5&version=NASB;SBLGNT)). For example, if Jesus Christ is glorified in the heavenlies, then so too is the Christian ([Eph 2:6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%202%3A6&version=NASB;SBLGNT)). Thus the Christian sees himself in this glorious identity through the reflected “mirror” of the Christian Scripture: that is, *I am [in] Christ and Christ is [in] me*.

The Book of James uses this illustration. Here the Christian understands his identity in Jesus Christ through what is heard and understood through the “mirror” of the Christian Scriptures, or Law of Liberty ([Jam 1:23-25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=James%201%3A23-25&version=NASB;SBLGNT)). However, if the same Christian walks away from this “mirror” and forgets his identity, he or she will “flip-flop” (double-minded) back into the ways of the world. The glory of this identity in Jesus Christ thus fades away from the mind's eye. The remedy to this problem is to “renew the mind” through consistent exposure to the [Christian] Scriptures ([Col 3:10](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Col%203%3A10&version=NASB;SBLGNT) and [Rom 12:1-2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Rom%2012%3A1-2&version=NASB;SBLGNT)).

Comment: The Greek can be interpreted as meaning either that we are observing something in the mirror or that we ourselves mirror something.  I think you could argue for your interpretation under the first interpretation, but it seems that the Greek Church Fathers (e.g. Chrysostom, Cyril of Jerusalem) understand the latter.

Comment: @TheNonTheologian -  The views of Chrysostom, Cyril of Jerusalem, and others are [at variance with the usage of the language and at variance with the context which lays the stress on free and unhindered seeing and not upon reflecting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6dsNd.png). What are _your_ thoughts in this regard?

Comment: I think the answer is in the next sentence of the source you quote:  "But it is urged in reply that Chrysostom may be trusted to know what Greek usage is, and as to the context the splendor which shone in Moses's face [v. 13] that which suggested this whole train of thought, was a reflection of what he saw on the mount."  I linked to Chrysostom's whole homily below.

Comment: I think there are many cases where modern translations are off, even when the translator is expertly schooled in Koine Greek, but not in the commentaries of the Church Fathers.  One example is John 5:27-28.  The literal Greek translations are all correct, but the sentences are punctuated incorrectly and lead to a heretical reading.  Chrysostom also points this out in one of his homilies.

Answer (score 2):

The NASB and other versions choose to translate this verse as if "we" are viewing our own reflection, but this is not actually what the verse is saying.  The word translated as "beholding" - κατοπτρίζω - can have the sense of both viewing a reflection and of reflecting something oneself (as a mirror).    A more appropriate translation might be:

> *But we all, with unveiled face reflecting as a mirror the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into the same image from glory to
> glory, even as from* [the] *Lord,* [the] *Spirit.*

This is the sense understood, for example, by the 4th century Byzantine (Greek) commentator, John Chrysostom:

> What is, “we reflecting as a mirror the glory of the Lord, are
> transformed into the same image”? This indeed was shown more clearly
> when the gifts of miracles were in operation; howbeit it is not even
> now difficult to see it, for one who hath believing eyes. For as soon
> as we are baptized, the soul beameth even more than the sun, being
> cleansed by the Spirit; and not only do we behold the glory of God,
> but from it also receive a sort of splendor. Just as if pure silver be
> turned towards the sun’s rays, it will itself also shoot forth rays,
> not from its own natural property merely but also from the solar
> lustre; so also doth the soul being cleansed and made brighter than
> silver, receive a ray from the glory of the Spirit, and send it back.
> Wherefore also he saith, “Reflecting as a mirror we are transformed
> into the same image from glory,” that of the Spirit, “to glory,” our
> own, that which is generated in us; and that, of such sort, as one
> might expect from the Lord the Spirit.
>
> [*Homily VII on the Second Epistle of Paul to the Corinthians*](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf112.v.vii.html)

Cyril of Jerusalem (4th century) also understands this sense:

> And ye were first anointed on the forehead, that ye might be delivered
> from the shame, which the first man who transgressed bore about with
> him everywhere; and that with unveiled face ye might reflect as a
> mirror the glory of the Lord
>
> [*Catechetical Lecture XXI*, "On the Mysteries: Chrism"](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf207.ii.xxv.html)

Understanding the the verse speaks of we ourselves reflecting the glory of God and not of our observing the glory of God, we can relate it to what Paul writes in Romans (8:14):

> *For as many as are led by the Spirit of God, these are the sons of God*

This is clearer from the greater pericope (v.17-18):

> *Now the Lord is the Spirit; and where the Spirit of* [the] *Lord* [is]*, there* [is] *freedom.*
>
> *But we all, with unveiled face reflecting as a mirror the glory of the Lord, are being transformed into the same image from glory to
> glory, even as from* [the] *Lord,* [the] *Spirit.*

This second verse reminds us that the goal and result of the Holy Spirit's leading us and working in us is our transformation into the image of Christ, an ongoing process (viz. "from glory to glory").

Answer (score 1):

Q. How does a believer "behold as in the mirror the glory of the Lord" as in 2 Corinthians 3:18?

A. By instead of looking through the veiled face of Moses at the Old Covenant (and believing that he/it still has glory), looking through the unveiled face of the apostles at the new covenant and the gospel. And in addition, "all of us" (including the apostles) are beholding "God" through the unveiled face of Jesus Christ, with Christ acting as the mirror of God's light:

> International Standard Version
>   Hebrews 1:3
>   He is the reflection of God's glory and the exact likeness of his being, and he holds everything together by his powerful word. After he had provided a cleansing from sins, he sat down at the right hand of the Highest Majesty

Important note: "exact likeness" is not Koine but Biblish. It is simply saying that he is the "figure" or "representation" of God's being.

In fact, Jesus could not be the "exact representation" of God's glory because if he were, the disciples could not have touched him, handled him, watched him, etc. as they did in 1 John 1:1 but if he were not a representation then handling him would not be handling God's "living expression" (usually translated as "Word of life").

If you please, the believer is transformed by gazing upon the glory of God in the unveiled face of Jesus Christ - through the unveiled face of the apostles.

Note that the face of Moses was also illuminated with the glory of God but it has come to fade by virtue of the greater light of the gospel of Jesus Christ:

> BSB 2 Cor 3:
>   7Now if the ministry of death, which was engraved in letters on stone, came with such glory that the Israelites could not gaze at the face of Moses because of its fleeting glory, 8will not the ministry of the Spirit be even more glorious? 9For if the ministry of condemnation was glorious, how much more glorious is the ministry of righteousness! 10Indeed, **what was once glorious has no glory now in comparison to the glory that surpasses it**. 11For if what was fading away came with glory, how much greater is the glory of that which endures!

Answer (score 0):

**How does a believer behold as in the mirror the glory of the Lord in  2 Corinthians 3:18?**

Adam was created as a perfect human being and reflected God's glory, however he sinned, and as his descendants we have all inherited sin ,and so fall short of the glory of God. Paul declares :**"For all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God. (Rom. 3:23 NASB)**

Christians are admonished to do all things for the glory of God: **" Whether, then, you eat or drink or whatever you do, do all to the glory of God.(1 Corinthians 10:31  NASB)**
However in order to be able to glorify God, first we have to get to know Him, John wrote: **"This is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent." John 17:3  (NASB).**

Admittedly it is not an easy task  as  Psalm 51:5  says, **"For I was born a sinner,yes, from the moment my mother conceived me."** However God will measure how well we strive to get to know him and  to achieve his standards, so that we can reflect his glory. We can do this by meditating on the scriptures and by prayer.

**MEDITATING ON THE SCRIPTURES.**

We have to make an  in- depth effort to study the scriptures  and get to know our creator  and his qualities, so that we can improve  our faith and our determination to continue restraining our sinful tendencies, so that we can reflect the glory of God . The Psalmist wrote:

Psalm 119:11  (NASB)

> " Your word I have treasured in my heart, That I may not sin against
>   You."

**BY PRAYER.**

We read in the scriptures that Jesus prayed to his Father on may occasions,  to help him  avoid temptation to sin. To reflect God's glory we must also persevere in payer , to help us  serve him in a manner acceptable to him, and to protect us to resist  temptation. (Mat. 6:13). Paul wrote:(Romans 12:12 MEV)

> "Rejoice in hope, be patient in suffering, persevere in prayer.

**HOW TO REFLECT GOD'S GLORY.**

**Christ Is Our Example:**

Jesus  was born  as a perfect human  being ,(John 1:14) and is the only one  who reflected God's glory through-out his life,  although, we are not perfect, Peter wrote that we should all try to follow his example:

1 Peter 2:21 (NASB)

> " For you have been called for this purpose, since Christ also
>   suffered for you, leaving you an example for you to follow in His
>   steps."

Jesus had tender warmth feeling for others,(Mark 10:13-16). Jesus felt sympathy for the leper,and " Jesus stretched out His hand and touched him, saying, “I am willing; be cleansed.” (Matthew 8:1-4). Jesus cares for others and feeds 3000, (John 6:1-13).  Jesus was forgiving: (Luke 5:17-26 NASB)

> 20 "When He saw their faith, He said to him, “Man, your sins are
>   forgiven you.”25 Immediately he rose before them, and took up that on
>   which he lay, and departed to his own house, glorifying God."

Christians with their conduct and speech  can influence others to give glory to God:

Matthew 5:16  (NASB)

> "Let your light shine before men in such a way that they may see your
>   good works, and glorify your Father who is in heaven." (Compare 1
>   Peter 2:12)

If Christians continuously respond to God's word and  become doers and not just hearers (James 1:22-25) they  will be transformed from glory to glory and will reflect the glory of God:

2 Corinthians 3:18  (NASB)

> " But we all, with unveiled face, beholding as in a mirror the glory
>   of the Lord, are being transformed into the same image from glory to
>   glory, just as from the Lord, the Spirit."

**BECOME IMITATORS OF GOD.**

To reflect God's glory we have to become  imitators of God. **"Therefore be imitators of God, as beloved children."Ephesians 5:1 (NASB)** ..  Since the whole world is under the influence of Satan the Devil, (1 john 5:19) Christians  have to make an effort to live  in a way that will not bring dishonor to God.

**If you love the Lord hate evil.**

Psalm 97:10 (MEV)

> 10 "You who love the Lord, hate evil! He preserves the lives of His
>   devoted ones; He delivers them from the hand of the wicked."

**1/ Be aware of false prophets, apostates and Antichrists.**

Jesus advised his followers to be on the watch for false prophets.

Matthew 7:15 (NASB)

> 15 “Beware of the false prophets, who come to you in sheep’s clothing,
>   but inwardly are ravenous wolves."

**Likewise about thirty years later Paul wrote.**

2 Thessalonians 2:3  (NASB)

> 3 "Let no one in any way deceive you, for it will not come unless the
>   apostasy comes first, and the man of lawlessness is revealed, the son
>   of destruction."

It is obvious that from the first century  false prophets,apostates and Antichrists have shrouded the word of God and spread deception about the teachings of Christ. Today there are thousands of Christian religions, due to the diversity of the teachings and interpretations of the scriptures, so  only by reading the scriptures can you  determine the Antichrist and their deceptions.

1 John 2:15  (NASB)

> 15 Do not love the world nor the things in the world. If anyone loves
>   the world, the love of the Father is not in him.

There are many things that God hates, Satanic gore, lies, violence, pornography, read horoscopes.(Romans 1:24-25) and many other things to be found in the scriptures. Some others are mentioned by Paul below.

1 Corinthians 5:11  (NASB)

> 11 "But actually, I wrote to you not to associate with any so-called
>   brother if he is an immoral person, or covetous, or an idolater, or a
>   reviler, or a drunkard, or a swindler—not even to eat with such a
>   one."

**Those who hate what is bad will not seek ways to indulge in it. On the other hand, people who do not hate it may physically refrain from it while mentally wishing that they could share in bad things.**

**3/Do not be idle gossipers and busybodies.**

1 Timothy 5:13 (MEV)

> 13 Besides that, they learn to be idle, and not only idle, wandering
>   around from house to house, but also gossips and busybodies, saying
>   what they ought not.

**4/ God is love.**

God is love and if we are to glorify God we should be loving, towards others, our family , relatives, works mates and the world in general, cultivating love will also prevent us from sinful tendencies.

1 John 4:16-19 Modern English Version (MEV)

> 16 "And we have come to know and to believe the love that God has for
>   us.God is love. Whoever lives in love lives in God, and God in him. 17
>   In this way God’s love is perfected in us, so that we may have
>   boldness on the Day of Judgment, because as He is, so are we in this
>   world."
>
> 18 "There is no fear in love, but perfect love casts out fear, because
>   fear has to do with punishment. Whoever fears is not perfect in
>   love.19 We love Him because He first loved us."

**CONCLUSION.**

A Christian’s conduct  and speech reflects on his faith. When observers make that connection​ , they see that the Christian’s fine conduct is a direct result of his faith and so ​it brings glory to God. Jesus said ," Let your light so shine before men that they may see your good works and glorify your Father who is in heaven."(Matthew 5:16 MEV)

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

We will reflect outwardly (as reflecting in a mirror) the glory of God for the world to visibly see who will then thank and praise God above as we are transformed (transfigured) into His image.  It is not our Light that they will see but the Light of God that is reflected as they see His Light reflected by us.

> 2 Corinthians 3:17-18 KJV (17)  *Now the Lord is that Spirit: and where
>   the Spirit of the Lord is, there is liberty. (18)  **But we all, with
>   open face beholding as in a glass the glory of the Lord, are changed
>   into the same image from glory to glory, even as by the Spirit of the
>   Lord**.*

“From glory to glory”….the glory within us shall be revealed outwardly for the world to visibly see and give glory to God.

This mystery has been hid from ages and from generations but is now made manifest to His saints within us and who will manifest the eternal life of Jesus outwardly in this world so that the nations shall see and the believers among them shall praise God above.

Christ in you, the hope of glory which will be made manifest for all to see.

> Colossians 1:25-27 KJV (25)  *Whereof I am made a minister, according
>   to the dispensation of God which is given to me for you, to fulfil the
>   word of God; (26)  Even the mystery which hath been hid from ages and
>   from generations, but now is made manifest to his saints: (27)  **To
>   whom God would make known what is the riches of the glory of this
>   mystery among the Gentiles; which is Christ in you, the hope of glory**:*

We are to die to sin always.  We are "dead" and our life is hid with Christ in God. this life is currently hid from this world but it doesn't stay hidden.

> Colossians 3:3-4 KJV (3)  **For ye are dead, and your life is hid with
>   Christ in God.**

That life (who is Christ) shall be made manifested outwardly for the world to see.  When He shall appear, we shall appear with Him in glory.  The glory within manifests outwardly.  Christ in us the hope of glory....the outward glory where the believing people of this world shall visibly see what it means to serve Him as we inherit His eternal life in this earth.

> (4)  ***When Christ, who is our life, shall appear, then shall ye also
>   appear with him in glory.***

The “thanksgiving of many redound to the glory of God”.   They will see His manifest Light in us and glorify Him. All those in the darkness of this world shall see the Light.

> 2 Corinthians 4:15-16 KJV (15)  **For all things are for your sakes,
>   that the abundant grace might through the thanksgiving of many redound
>   to the glory of God.**

The believing people of this world shall only believe when they see His eternal life made manifest through us….like Thomas (doubting Thomas). they will praise God:  "my Lord and my God".

> John 20:27-30 KJV (27)  *Then saith he to Thomas, Reach hither thy
>   finger, and behold my hands; and reach hither thy hand, and thrust it
>   into my side: and be not faithless, but believing. (28)  And Thomas
>   answered and said unto him, My Lord and my God.*

But blessed are those who have not seen His eternal life yet and have believed.

> (29)  *Jesus saith unto him, Thomas, **because thou hast seen me, thou
>   hast believed: blessed are they that have not seen, and yet have
>   believed.***

We who FIRST trust in Christ are to be to the “praise of His glory” as the world will only believe when they visibly see His eternal life .  We first trust in Christ who opens up the Scriptures to our hearing ears.

We trust in what the Lord says.. who is the Spirit (Breath) that transforms the Scriptures into its heavenly meaning.   We believe in what He says.

We behold the Word of Truth.

We hear the Word of Truth….as opposed to the word of men who have been wresting the Scriptures to their own destruction.

We hear and believe and are sealed with that Holy Spirit of promise….the promise of the redemption of our mortal bodies in this earth.  This is a here-and-now thing in this earth and not a after we “die and go to heaven” thing.   The whole creation awaits for the manifestation of the sons of God.

> Ephesians 1:12-14 KJV (12)  ***That we should be to the praise of his
>   glory, who first trusted in Christ.*** (13)  In whom ye also trusted,
>   **after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation**:
>   in whom also **after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy
>   Spirit of promise**,

The Spirit is the earnest of our inheritance (the manifest eternal life of Jesus) and the redemption of the “purchased possession” is our mortal bodies being transformed into His glorious body in this earth where the nations of this world shall visibly see and then praise God.

They (the nations of this world) shall visibly see and praise Him…. “unto the praise of His glory”.   We put away this earthly, sin humbled body in order to put on Jesus Christ who is eternal.

> (14)  **Which is the earnest of our inheritance until the redemption of
>   the purchased possession, unto the praise of his glory.**

Our mortal body is the “purchased possession” of the Lord as it is the temple of the Holy Spirit (the earnest of our inheritance) which is in us.  We are bought with a price.

> 1 Corinthians 6:19-20 KJV (19)  *What? know ye not that your body is
>   the temple of the Holy Ghost which is in you, which ye have of God,
>   and ye are not your own? (20)  **For ye are bought with a price:**
>   therefore glorify God in your body, and in your spirit, which are
>   God's.*

The “purchase” is the mortal body which is sealed with the Holy Spirit of promise (the promise of eternal life…continuing “many days”).

That which is “open” is the revealing of the eternal life of Jesus in this earthen vessel (body) for the world to see.  “Baruch” means “to bless” as others shall see the “open” evidence of the eternal life of Jesus and praise God above.  They will bless God instead of the cursing of His name that they are doing presently.

> Jeremiah 32:13-14 KJV (13)  *And I charged Baruch before them, saying,
>   (14)  Thus saith the LORD of hosts, the God of Israel; Take these
>   evidences, **this evidence of the purchase, both which is sealed, and
>   this evidence which is open; and put them in an earthen vessel, that
>   they may continue many days**.*

But we (who first trust Christ) must “hear” and believe in the Son of which the Father is well pleased in as He opens up the Scriptures to our understanding.

The Light shall shine within our hearts as we hear His voice.  This is the “sign of the Son of man” speaking to us from Heaven.   There will be no mistaking His voice as that Light shall dawn within our very own hearts….the “morning star” shall arise in our own hearts signifying that this is His Son speaking.

False prophets do not have this effect upon our hearts as they must rely on speaking flattery (wonders with man's admiration in mind)and outward signs (performing outward signs of supposed inward realities).

> 2 Peter 1:19-21 KJV (19)  *We have also a more sure word of prophecy;
>   whereunto ye do well that ye take heed, **as unto a light that shineth
>   in a dark place, until the day dawn, and the day star arise in your
>   hearts: (20)  Knowing this first, that no prophecy of the scripture is
>   of any private interpretation.** (21)  For the prophecy came not in old
>   time by the will of man: but holy men of God spake as they were moved
>   by the Holy Ghost.*

The Light shines in the heart first....and we know this is the Son speaking.

> 2 Corinthians 4:6 KJV (6)  *For God, who commanded the light to shine
>   out of darkness, **hath shined in our hearts,** **to give the light of the
>   knowledge of the glory of God in the face of Jesus Christ**.*

His words shall be the interpreted words of the Scriptures.  His words are the “holy angels”…the holy messages of God…..the true and faithful sayings of God.

He interprets the Scriptures.  It is no coincidence that Moses and Elijah...the Law and the Prophets... “talked with Him” on the mountain in the Transfiguration as He interprets them...changes them into their heavenly interpretation.

They spoke of His “decease”…that is, exit or exodus…as His eternal life is to be made manifest in this world which had been suppressed by false prophets and the wresting of the Scriptures to their own mortal destruction from this earth.  They have no understanding of the Scriptures and they perish from this world in their misunderstanding

> Luke 9:26-32 KJV (26)  **For whosoever shall be ashamed of me and of my
>   words, of him shall the Son of man be ashamed, when he shall come in
>   his own glory, and in his Father's, and of the holy angels.** (27)  But
>   I tell you of a truth, there be some standing here, which shall not
>   taste of death, till they see the kingdom of God. (28)  And it came to
>   pass about an eight days after these sayings, he took Peter and John
>   and James, and went up into a mountain to pray. (29)  And as he
>   prayed, the fashion of his countenance was altered, and his raiment
>   was white and glistering. (30)  **And, behold, there talked with him two
>   men, which were Moses and Elias: (31)  Who appeared in glory, and
>   spake of his decease which he should accomplish at Jerusalem**.

We who have been “heavy with sleep” are to awake to His righteousness and perceive His glory.

> (32)  ***But Peter and they that were with him were heavy with sleep: and
>   when they were awake, they saw his glory, and the two men that stood
>   with him.***

We must awake to righteousness to behold His glory and “put on” incorruption”.  We must put on Jesus Christ who is incorruptible and immortal so that death is swallowed up in victory.  We must put on the heavenly Man….Jesus Christ our Lord…so that we may inherit His eternal life in this earth for the world to see.

Flesh-and-blood acting men shall not inherit the kingdom of God which is everlasting and not a dying kingdom. they will hear and not believe as they will not put on Jesus Christ who is incorruptible and immortal at the transformation of the Scriptures into the faithful and true Sayings of God.

> 1 Corinthians 15:53-55 KJV (53)  ***For this corruptible must put on
>   incorruption, and this mortal must put on immortality.*** (54)  So when
>   this corruptible shall have put on incorruption, and this mortal shall
>   have put on immortality, then shall be brought to pass the saying that
>   is written, **Death is swallowed up in victory.** (55)  O death, where is
>   thy sting? O grave, where is thy victory?

We have this treasure within our earthen vessels…the mortal body.  We must keep His “daily” sacrifice (always dying to sin)…always bearing about in this body the dying of the Lord Jesus…so that the life also of Jesus might be made manifest (outwardly shining)in our body.

> 2 Corinthians 4:10-11 KJV (10)  *Always bearing about in the body the
>   dying of the Lord Jesus, t**hat the life also of Jesus might be made
>   manifest in our body**. (11)  For we which live are alway delivered unto
>   death for Jesus' sake, **that the life also of Jesus might be made
>   manifest in our mortal flesh**.*

The good news of the kingdom of God that it is an EVERLASTING kingdom and not a dying one as preached by those who say we must “die and go to heaven”.  They preach their covenant with death and their agreement with the grave instead.    The good news of Christ has been hidden from them.   The Light of the glorious good news of Christ who is the image of God does not enlighten them as they only serve for their own belly...the "god" of this world.

We shall enter in to that everlasting kingdom in this earth (under the whole heaven) if we hear and believe.   We shall “continue many days” (having eternal life) to see that.  We shall live to see all dominions of this earth serving and obeying Him.

> Daniel 7:27 KJV (27)  And the kingdom and dominion, and the greatness
>   of the kingdom under the whole heaven, shall be given to the people of
>   the saints of the most High, **whose kingdom is an everlasting kingdom,**
>   and all dominions shall serve and obey him.

Answer (score 0):

The scriptures are deep. I am very blessed by the expositions I have read.

There are also dimensions of the same scripture that reveals the Lord's Glory on the INSIDE (invisibility and can be seen by the occultist) of the believer.

There are dimensions of the same scripture that proves that the believer is eternally saved and by Grace and Grace only.

For the purposes of time, I am going to be sharing few things bordering on 2nd Cor 3:18, rightaway.

2nd Cor 4:6-18; For God who commanded the Light to shine out of darkness, hath shined in our hearts, to give the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in the FACE of Jesus Christ. But we have this treasure in earthen vessels, that the excellency of the power may be of God, and not of us.

1st John 3:9
1st John 3:2;
Gen 1:1-3;
Exodus 33 and 34;
Hebrews 1-3.

We are going to be looking at 2nd Cor 3:18 viz-a-viz the highlighted scriptures above.

The FACE of Jesus Christ encapsulates all His glory. His glory being all that he represents in heaven, earth and under the earth: that represents His IDENTITY (Glory). The light of the KNOWLEDGE (revelation) of the glory of God is captured in His FACE.

Let's delve into few of this Revelation which is this knowledge of the glory of God in 2nd Cor 4:6-18 that Paul is talking about and relate everything back to 2nd Cor 3:18.

By comparing spiritual things with spiritual, the Lord does things in PATTERNS or in SHADOWS or in TYPES before the real thing is accomplished: like the Adam was declared in scriptures as the FIGURE, or if you would, the SHADOW of He that is to come, the Lord Jesus; Moses's instruction was to pattern the ARK according to the real ARK in heaven and to see to it that nothing changes in the earthly Ark compared to the one in heaven. Other examples of patterns or shadows abound in scriptures. Sticking to Patterns, shadows, figures ensure the flow of power from the Godhead.

Gen 1:2 speaks of the Spirit of God hovering over the FACE of the waters.

In biblical parlance, water can represent mankind as seen in Ecclesiastes 11:1-6. Casting our bread upon the waters speaks of giving to men and how that we shall find it after many days: more like, give and it shall be given unto you.

Gen 1:3 went on to say, "God said, let there be LIGHT" after the Spirit hovered over the FACE of the waters. The face of anything; a brand or a person is the FULLEST REPRESENTATION of that thing,i.e., fullest identity. Two men have completely represented mankind; the 1st and the last Adams. The last Adam being the Lord Jesus.

At the Jordan, that which was a TYPE in Genesis 1:2-3, was fully accomplished when the Spirit of God descends on the Lord Jesus as he rises from the river whose type was the waters in Genesis 1:2. The hovering of the Spirit in Genesis 1:2 was necessary, as it were, to endue the FACE of the waters(mankind) with the power that is necessary for mankind to bring forth the Christ who will be incarnated as the Lord Jesus who will be born and anoited by the Holy Ghost when He rises from the river (waters) at His baptism at the Jordan. Notice that it was after the Spirit hovered over the FACE of the waters that God then commanded the LIGHT to come forth and there was Light. The Christ in Genesis 1 is the FACE (the Representative) of the waters (mankind). If we recall that visible light did not appear after this command was made until the 4th day when the light of the sun and of the moon appeared, then it will become clear that the Light in Genesis 1:3 cannot be the light of the moon and the sun but the Christ who is SELF-EXISTING having been commanded to show forth by God in Genesis 1:3 as it is by the Christ that creation was to take place. Recall, all things were made by Him and without Him was not anything made that was made as captured in John 1:3. It is the command that the Light come forth that Paul recounts in 2nd Cor 4:6-18.

So, if we understand that what is happening in Genesis here is a TYPE, a SHADOW, a FIGURE or a PATTERN of that reality at the Jordan where the Holy Ghost hovered, as it were, over the Jordan and alighted on the Lord Jesus, then the mystery of the FACE of Jesus (as we progress this discus) can be fully appreciated in 2nd Cor 4:6-18 and 2nd Cor 3:18.

In 2nd Cor 3:18, .....as in a mirror, the glory of Jesus can also be construed as Jesus' FACE representing that mirror reflecting His glory which becomes a yardstick for the believer to see his truest spiritual status through the light of the word which is the mirror and the Lord Jesus. The Word of God mirrors the true spiritual status of the believer. Recall we are admonished in scriptures not to forget who we are like a man who after observing himself in a mirror turns away and suddenly forgets who he is: James 1:2-4.

Recall in Exodus 33 and 34, the FACE of Jesus was also brought to focus in the discus between The Lord (Yahweh) as "The Lord" is translated, "Yahweh" in the original text; speaking of the Lord Jesus in His pre-incarnate manifestation to the Jews in the OT.

Here, Moses sought to know Him; to see His FACE. For what personality is without a face which ought to be his IDENTITY? The Lord objected because Moses will die if he sees the Lord's FACE: that is, he will be "TRANSLATED"(NB as we will revisit that word); but rather opted to allow Moses behold or see Him from His back parts so that as He passes by (while He removed his eitherto placed hand on Moses, having placed Moses in a CLIFT of the ROCK (a figure or type of Himself)) His IDENTITY, which represented His FACE in this context, can be made known to Moses WHEN He begins to make declarations or proclamations of whom He is (the stuff He is made off).

For what a man has going on, on their inside, which is truely who they are, can be decoded in expressions on their face helping others to identify who they are. It is also on their face their month is located and when they speak, things from their hearts begin to manifest and their true self is revealed. Out of the abundance of the heart, the mouth speaks.

So, the Lord made the following declarations," The Lord, The Lord God, merciful and gracious, long-suffering, and abundant in goodness and truth, keeping mercy for thousands, forgiving iniquity and transgression and sin..... I stopped here because some of the totems of the heritage of the Church, the Body of Christ is well captured by these declarations.

The revelation in 2nd Cor 3:18 and 2nd Cor 4:6-8 is once more captured in types or shadows in Exodus 33 and 34.

Hebrews 1-3 speaks of the Lord Jesus Christ being the BRIGHTNESS of His glory and the EXPRESS IMAGE of His Person. We see here that the image of God is the Lord Jesus Christ; the same image 2nd Cor 3:18 is talking about that the believer is being TRANSFORMED into from glory to glory: meaning the believer is constantly changing as the knowledge of the glory of God (is being revealed in the FACE of Jesus, the Son of God, shining in his heart) is constantly being beheld (just by looking into it,i.e.,just by searching the scriptures bordering on the knowledge of the revelation of the GLORY of our Lord jesus) in the FACE of Jesus (that same spiritual mirror which is the Word of God).

If we understand this, then it becomes clearer what scriptures are saying in 1st John 3:9 regarding how that He who is born of the Spirit of God CANNOT sin and not will not sin,i.e., it is impossible for the believer to sin. If this is true, why then is 2nd Cor 3:18 saying that the believer still has need of continuous transformation from glory to glory since it has become impossible for the believer to sin according to John?

Then it becomes obvious that the Spirit of man could not have been what Paul was addressing in 2nd Cor 3:18 but his soul where continous sanctification goes on,i.e., continuous cleansing of his sin and his constantly approaching perfection in his soul realm and because it is not possible for man's soul to be perfect as long as his body is yet fallen and would always fall under the damand of his flesh, 1st John 3:2 becomes in full alignment with 2nd Cor 3:18. Here, it is written that ...now are we the sons of God, and it doth not yet appear what we shall be: but we know that, when He shall appear (descends from the lower heavens in the cloud at his 2nd coming) we shall be like Him; for we shall see Him as He is (the TRANSLATION, i.e., translated instantly).

By this time, if we are going to SEE (beholding as in a mirror which is a Type) Him as He is (which will mean our Faces making direct constant with His FACE, the real thing and not as a Type anymore in 2nd Cor 3:18, same thing Moses wanted but was shown His back parts instead (Exodus 34:20-23) but shall grant the Church, His Body when He appears in the lower heavens at His return) then, other than our souls undergoing continous sanctification as in 2nd Cor 3:18, we shall become the SPLITTING IMAGE of Him (1st John 3:2): becomes exactly as He looks; with us having a resurrected body as well which will mean that our souls and bodies have become completely REBORN where before now this rebirth has been gradual for the soul but never even happened to the body of the believer at all when he became saved.

In conclusion, it is impossible for the believer to sin where his spirit is concerned and 2nd Cor 3:18 and 2nd Cor 4:6-18 make it possible for the believer's soul to be experiencing glorious transformation from one degree of glory to another degree of glory,i.e., soulish BRIGHTNESS like that of the Son of God in Hebrews 1--.....who being the BRIGHTNESS of His GLORY and the EXPRESS IMAGE of His Person..... This means the believer has this access just by looking (beholding) that mirror, the Word concerning the KNOWLEDGE of the REVELATION of the GLORY OF GOD (brightness of God in Hebrew) in the FACE (that mirror of the Word) of Jesus. I am saying by the grace of God our Father, that when the believer has not even done any act of the fruits of the Spirit, just by beholding this constant revelation knowledge of the Person of Jesus, the Son of God, he bigins to experience this transformation from one degree of glory to another degree of glory; so much so that the occultist can see this BRIGHTNESS (Glory as per 2nd Cor 3:18 and that Hebrews 1 talked about) in and around the believer without the believer even knowing. Every direction that the FACE of Jesus turns, it can also manifest a mundane experience for the believer in the area of his needs in life,i.e.,the Lord's promises in His word as masticated by the believer in faith produces results for him.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.